# Group 2-level array data using multiple column values to form a 5-level array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, grouping

I would like to transform the following indexed array of associative arrays:

```
[
    0 => [
        "question_id" => "1e61c2b5-9932-4bce-aa73-eb45bb929be1",
        "segment_name" => "expo",
        "brand_name" => "Aucun",
        "count" => 1623
    ],
    1 => [
        "question_id" => "1e61c2b5-9932-4bce-aa73-eb45bb929be1",
        "segment_name" => "no expo",
        "brand_name" => "Aucun",
        "count" => 3965
    ],
    2 => [
        "question_id" => "1e61c2b5-9932-4bce-aa73-eb45bb929be1",
        "segment_name" => "expo",
        "brand_name" => "Rebelle",
        "count" => 156
    ],
    3 => [
        "question_id" => "1e61c2b5-9932-4bce-aa73-eb45bb929be1",
        "segment_name" => "no expo",
        "brand_name" => "Rebelle",
        "count" => 378
    ],
    4 => [
        "question_id" => "ffc77534-4925-40d2-a193-b0ee7605f359",
        "segment_name" => "expo",
        "brand_name" => "Aucun",
        "count" => 1572
    ],
    5 => [
        "question_id" => "ffc77534-4925-40d2-a193-b0ee7605f359",
        "segment_name" => "no expo",
        "brand_name" => "Aucun",
        "count" => 3647
    ],
    6 => [
        "question_id" => "ffc77534-4925-40d2-a193-b0ee7605f359",
        "segment_name" => "expo",
        "brand_name" => "Rebelle",
        "count" => 169
    ],
    7 => [
        "question_id" => "ffc77534-4925-40d2-a193-b0ee7605f359",
        "segment_name" => "no expo",
        "brand_name" => "Rebelle",
        "count" => 361
    ]
]
```

Into:

```
[
    0 => [
        'question_id' => '1e61c2b5-9932-4bce-aa73-eb45bb929be1',
        'brands' => [
            0 => [
                'name' => 'Aucun',
                'count' => [
                    'expo' => 1623,
                    'no expo' => 3965,
                ]
            ],
            1 => [
                'name' => 'Rebelle',
                'count' => [
                    'expo' => 156,
                    'no expo' => 378,
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    1 => [
        'question_id' => 'ffc77534-4925-40d2-a193-b0ee7605f359',
        'brands' => [
            0 => [
                'name' => 'Aucun',
                'count' => [
                    'expo' => 1572,
                    'no expo' => 3647,
                ]
            ],
            1 => [
                'name' => 'Rebelle',
                'count' => [
                    'expo' => 169,
                    'no expo' => 361,
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

i.e group by **question_id** and then regroup counts by **brand_name** :
[image]

This is what I have done so far:

```
$groupedData = [];
foreach ($sampleArray as $row) {
    $row[$row['segment_name']] = $row['count'];
    unset($row['segment_name']);
    unset($row['count']);
    $groupedData[$row['question_id']][] = array_splice($row, 1, count($row));
}
```

How can I achieve this using PHP?

Comment: @Mohs The input data in your image conflicts with the plain text representation of your input array.  Please clarify the input array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for in a general manner:

```
<?php
$input = [
  [
    'question_id' => "1e61c2b5-9932-4bce-aa73-eb45bb929be1",
    'segment_id' => 1,
    'segment_name' => "expo",
    'brand_name' => "Aucun",
    'count' => 1623],
  [
    'question_id' => "1e61c2b5-9932-4bce-aa73-eb45bb929be1",
    'segment_id' => 2,
    'segment_name' => "no expo",
    'brand_name' => "Aucun",
    'count' => 3965],
  [
    'question_id' => "1e61c2b5-9932-4bce-aa73-eb45bb929be1", 
    'segment_id' => 1,
    'segment_name' => "expo",
    'brand_name' => "Rebelle",
    'count' => 15],
  [
    'question_id' => "1e61c2b5-9932-4bce-aa73-eb45bb929be1", 
    'segment_id' => 2,
    'segment_name' => "no expo",
    'brand_name' => "Rebelle",
    'count' => 378]
];

$output = [];
array_walk ($input, function($entry) use (&$output) {
  list($question_id, $segment_id, $segment_name, $brand_name, $count) = array_values($entry);
  if ( ! array_key_exists($question_id, $output)) {
    $output[$question_id] = [
      'question_id' => $question_id,
      'brands' => []
    ];
  }
  if ( ! array_key_exists($brand_name, $output[$question_id]['brands'])) {
    $output[$question_id]['brands'][$brand_name] = [
      'name' => $brand_name,
      'count' => []
    ];
  }
  if ( ! array_key_exists($segment_name, $output[$question_id]['brands'][$brand_name]['count'])) {
    $output[$question_id]['brands'][$brand_name]['count'][$segment_name] = 0;
  }
  $output[$question_id]['brands'][$brand_name]['count'][$segment_name] += $count;
});

$output = array_values($output);
array_walk($output, function(&$question) use (&$output) {
  $question['brands'] = array_values($question['brands']);
});

print_r($output);
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 1e61c2b5-9932-4bce-aa73-eb45bb929be1
            [brands] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Aucun
                            [count] => Array
                                (
                                    [expo] => 1623
                                    [no expo] => 3965
                                )
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Rebelle
                            [count] => Array
                                (
                                    [expo] => 15
                                    [no expo] => 378
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

To execute the two levels of grouping, you must maintain two levels of temporary keys.  Use `isset()` to check if a level key exists in the result array before pushing the new values in the appropriate way.

Use [array destructuring](https://stitcher.io/blog/array-destructuring-with-list-in-php) to create concise variables in your loop so that the dynamic keys are easier to read.  You can also use `list()`, `[]`, or `extract()`, but I prefer this modern function-less technique.

When finished looping, you will need to re-index the `brands` subarrays and the first level keys.

If your data is guaranteed to not contain repeated subarray groups (in other words, you don't need to sum count values), then you can remove the final `else` branch and change the last `elseif` to `else`.

When pushing new data into an array using square brace syntax, you don't need to instantiate any parent levels in advance -- just declare the deep data with all of the appropriate keys.

The following process will only write data to the output array once -- it doesn't potentially overwrite any already declared data.  Each iteration will make either 1, 2 or 3 calls of `isset()` instead of always making 3 `array_key_exists()` calls per iteration as shown in @arkascha's snippet.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GlngM)) ([Demo if no recurring 5th level keys](https://3v4l.org/GpObs))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as ['question_id' => $q, 'segment_name' => $s, 'brand_name' => $b, 'count' => $c]) {
    if (!isset($result[$q])) {
        // create structure from first level
        $result[$q] = [
            'question_id' => $q,
            'brands' => [
                $b => [
                    'name' => $b,
                    'count' => [
                        $s => $c
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]; 
    } elseif (!isset($result[$q]['brands'][$b])) {
        // create structure from third level
        $result[$q]['brands'][$b] = [
            'name' => $b,
            'count' => [
                $s => $c
            ]
        ];
    } elseif (!isset($result[$q]['brands'][$b]['count'][$s])) {
        // create structure from fifth level
        $result[$q]['brands'][$b]['count'][$s] = $c;
    } else {
        // add recurring fifth level value to prexisting value
        $result[$q]['brands'][$b]['count'][$s] += $c;
    }
}

foreach ($result as &$row) {
    $row['brands'] = array_values($row['brands']);
}

var_export(array_values($result));
```

---

Of course, if you will never have recurring/conflicting data on any level, then you don't actually need any conditions at all.  Note that the following snippet will overwrite pre-existing value with the same value as there are no checks -- but no damage to the data.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7UQPB))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as ['question_id' => $q, 'segment_name' => $s, 'brand_name' => $b, 'count' => $c]) {
    $result[$q]['question_id'] = $q;
    $result[$q]['brands'][$b]['name'] = $b;
    $result[$q]['brands'][$b]['count'][$s] = $c;
}

foreach ($result as &$row) {
    $row['brands'] = array_values($row['brands']);
}

var_export(array_values($result));
```